# ReCaptcha implementation on a JSF/Richfaces application

Tags: jsf, richfaces, captcha, recaptcha

I need to implement a captcha which also support audio option. This is why I am trying to implement ReCaptcha.

I have been able to display the captcha on my page by doing the following:

```
<f:verbatim>
    #{myBean.captcha}
</f:verbatim>
```

Bean:

```
public String getCaptcha() {
    ReCaptcha captcha = ReCaptchaFactory.newReCaptcha("key1", "key2", false);
    String html = captcha.createRecaptchaHtml(null,null);
    return html;
}
```

The problem I am having is that I am displaying the Captcha in a `<h:form>`.

Since I am using JSF/Richfaces, when I submit the form, how do I get the value entered in the Captcha and pass it back to the Bean along with all the other values that the user entered in the form for verification? ReCaptcha has its own input field.

Help Greatly appreciated!

In addition to the initial problem, when I do click the audio button, I can hear "Please enter the following numbers: .......", I can hear the numbers but problem is that the image doesnt show numbers but letters, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're working with SimpleCaptcha? I don't see a `ReCaptcha` in the class hierarchy for that project

Comment: I have tried SimpleCaptcha but it will not fit my needs. I am now trying to implement ReCaptcha.

Comment: I'd remove the "*I have already implemented SimpleCaptcha*" from your question; it's confusing and leads readers to believe you're showing a sample of a SimpleCaptcha

Comment: Isn't the submitted value just available as request parameter? Have you checked the generated HTML output and/or the HTTP traffic monitor to figure the request parameter name? Or are you also new to basic HTML and HTTP and you actually needed assistance in that?

Comment: Like mentioned by Balus in the new version of ReCaptcha the user response was also submitted within the form to the backend.